# Why I can not assign the width and height values in the fields?

Tags: android

Why I can not assign the width and height values in the fields? When I test the following code with `Toast` class, the fields have the `0` value still.It seems after running the `post` method the values will be destroyed. How Can I prevent from this event?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
RelativeLayout re;
int width,height;
  protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
  super.onCreate(bundle);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  re = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.re);
  re.post(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
  width=re.getWidth();
        height=re.getHeight();
    }
});
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(width) + "  " + String.valueOf(height), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

Comment: Why you need Runnable class here? Any specific reasons?

Comment: I want get the width and the height from the `RelativeLayout`. the `post` method is correct, because when I use the `Toast` class in the `post` method I can see the width and the height.

Comment: Yes exactly that is the reason i asked. Here you don't need Post class. Just add width=re.getWidth();
        height=re.getHeight(); outside of runnable thread and check the toast

Comment: The body on the `run()` method is executed *after* showing the toast, hence you'll see `0`'s for the width and height. As a result, any logic depending on the width and height values will also have to be executed *inside* or *after* the `Runnable`. FYI: by posting a `Runnable`, it gets queued up in the view's internal message queue. It means it is *not* executed right away, but rather *after* any pending messages (such as measuring and laying out the view - that's why it's valid to get the view's width and height *inside* `run()` and not earlier).

Answer (score 1):

You can try with below code..

```
re.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

  public void onGlobalLayout() {
    height = re.getHeight();
    width = re.getWidth();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(width) + "  " + String.valueOf(height), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
});
```

Comment: This is no different from moving the toast to inside the `run()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Show the toast in your post method. Showing it outside the post method will let the width and height become equal to 0 as the relative layout is still not drawn on the screen. Post method will execute its code when the relative layout is drawn on the screen.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    RelativeLayout re;
    int width, height;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        re = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.re);
        re.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                width = re.getWidth();
                height = re.getHeight();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(width) + "  " + String.valueOf(height), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```